# how to create record component using react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to create react component for recording screen of web browser 
Is there anybody can know how to do this 
Please help me 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

nice to meet you 
you can use **react-media-recorder** library in your code
please try like below: 
Install **react-media-recorder** library using **npm**

```
npm i react-media-recorder
```

then

```
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";

const RecordView = () => {
  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl } =
    useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{status}</p>
      <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
      <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
      <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay loop />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Best Regards